# Difference between covariant and contravariant differential operator

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, differentiation

What is the difference between $\partial_\mu$ and $\partial^\mu$ ? Is there a need for the distinction between these guys in special relativity at all?.
As far as I know $\partial_\mu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial(ct)},\frac{\partial }{\partial x},\frac{\partial }{\partial y},\frac{\partial }{\partial z} \right)$
What would be the alternative representation for $\partial^\mu$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same thing as you raise or lower indices. Namely $\partial^\mu=\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}$, so $$ (\partial^\mu)=(-\frac{\partial}{\partial ct},\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}}). $$

The notation is unambigous $\partial$ and $\eta$ commute. The same is also true for GR with $\nabla$ and $g$, since $\nabla$ is metric-compatible.